# Drag&Drop on a Gallery View

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I'm trying to implement a simple Drag&Drop from a Gallery in a ImageView via a touch event.The problem is now I can't slide through gallery to select an image because the event is interpreted as an touch event.And my touCh event is just the drag&drop implementation!
Here's the code that implements the onTouch():

```
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    switch(arg1.getActionMasked()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: if(arg0 instanceof Gallery){
        ImageView tmp = (ImageView) gallery.getSelectedView();
        _im = new ImageView(this);
        _im.setLayoutParams(tmp.getLayoutParams());
        _im.setImageDrawable(tmp.getDrawable());
        mLayout.addView(_im);
        return true;
    }break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:if(_im != null){
        int x = (int)arg1.getX();
        int y = (int)arg1.getY();
        setAbsoluteLocationCentered(_im, x, y);
        return true;
    } break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:if (arg0 instanceof ImageView){
        _im.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        _im.setImageDrawable(null);
        mLayout.removeView(_im);
        //this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        _im = null;
        System.gc();
        return true;
    } break;
    default: return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now every time i try to slide through gallery my onTouch event is triggered!
Can you guys point me to some resources that can help me or just give an idea on what things to try?. There very few res about drag&drop and almost all of them use features implemented in Honeycomb.I can only use api available until android 2.2.